Need help with proof of an auxiliary result in Analysis I, Terence Tao
I attempt to prove the below result which is needed to prove an overall result in Analysis I, Terrance Tao. For reference, that overall result is Theorem 6.1.19 (Limit Laws) part (e).

Any sequence whose elements are non-zero, and which converges to a
non-zero limit, is bounded away from zero.


Here's my attempt:
Let $(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-zero real numbers (i.e., $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n \geq m$) that converges to a non-zero real number $x$. To show $(x_n)_{n=m}^\infty$ is bounded away from zero is to show there exists a real number $c > 0$ such that $|x_n| \geq c$ for all $n \geq m$.
Well, with $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n \geq m$, we must have $|x_n| > 0$ for all $n \geq m$. By an earlier result in the text (between any two reals, you can find another real), we know there exists a real number $c$ such that
$$
|x_n| > c >0
$$
for all $n \geq m$. This is what we wanted to show, so we are done.

My concern is that I did not use anywhere in the proof the assumption that $x \neq 0$, which makes me think I did something wrong. But I can't pinpoint any logical flaw. Could someone help me address the issue, if there even is one?

So, for fixed $n$ you find a number $c_n$ such that $|x_n|>c_n>0$. With this result, there is no reason to believe that $c_n$ is always the same. Take for instance the sequence $x_n=1/n$, you can't find such $c$. So you must use the hypothesis that $(x_n)$ has a non-zero limit.

Hint: Call $\lim x_n = L$ and consider an interval $(L-\varepsilon,L+\varepsilon)$. that does not contains $0$.

Thanks for your input @YgorArthur. I agree that $c_n$ can vary depending on $n$, and I guess I cannot take $c$ to be the minimum of all the $c_n$ since that's not guaranteed to exist. I'll have to think about this a little more then.

Without loss of generality, the sequence converges to $~L > 0,~$ with $~L = 2\epsilon.~$ There can exist only a finite number of elements such that beyond these elements, $$|L - a_n| < \epsilon \implies ~L - \epsilon < a_n < L + a_n.$$  So, after a finite number of elements, the sequence is clearly bounded between $$L - \epsilon ~~\text{and} ~~L + \epsilon.$$  Further in the finite sequence ${a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{n-1}},~$ none of the elements are equal to $~0.$

Suppose $x_n \to x.$ Then $x\neq0.$ Let $\varepsilon = |x|/2.$. Pick $N$ such that $n>N \implies |x_n - x|<\varepsilon.$ For $n>N$ we have $|x_n| = |x + x_n -x| \geq |x| - \varepsilon = \varepsilon.$ The inequality follows from the triangle inequality. Let $c=\min{\varepsilon,|x_1|,|x_2|,\ldots,|x_N|},$ then $c>0$ and $|x_n|\geq c$ for all $n.$
